# Pass no. of pages arguement to Drupal views pager

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have created views with display as page. In pager there is option to set no. of page to show. How can I set this dynamically by passing it through url? I can pass the page using 
`?page=2` and offset using `?offset=2` but I cant find a way to pass the no. of pages to show.

Comment: Are you talking about number of pages or number of items per page?

Comment: no. of items to be skipped. I want it to be passed through url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't quite get what you are asking about, but you should be able to examine `$view->pager` in a [hook_views_pre_build](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21docs%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7) and do what you want.  For example, this is a snippet of code I have used in Drupal 6 and Views 2 to set the number of items per page:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_build (&$view)
{
    if ($_GET["perpage"]) {
        $perpage = check_plain($_GET["perpage"]);

        if (is_numeric($perpage) && (int) $perpage > 1) {
            $view->pager["items_per_page"] = (int) $perpage;
        } else if ($perpage == "all") {
            $view->pager["use_pager"] = false;
            $view->pager["items_per_page"] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```