# How to expose to users filter for changing views items limit for pagination?

Tags: 7, views, paging

As in question, is this possible via UI or only custom form must be created?

Comment: Why my question is voted to close? Please attach comments.

Comment: The close votes are for "not a real question".  I think I understand what you are asking.  It is a near duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/pass-no-of-pages-arguement-to-drupal-views-pager, but asked in a slightly(?) different manner.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is actually being asked here - try to make the same effort in creating the question that you would like users to spend answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this manually.  I typically edit views-view.tpl.php file to build up a "items per page" list w/ links and tack on a `perpage=` GET argument.  You can do the same with a preprocess for the view, but I am spacing on what it is called.

I then implement a [hook_views_pre_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7):

```
function mymodule_views_pre_build (&$view)
{
  if ($_GET["perpage"]) {
    $perpage = check_plain($_GET["perpage"]);

    if (is_numeric($perpage) && (int) $perpage > 1) {
      $view->pager["items_per_page"] = (int) $perpage;
    } else if ($perpage == "all") {
      $view->pager["use_pager"] = false;
      $view->pager["items_per_page"] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The last time I remember doing this was with Drupal 6 and Views 2, so you may need to adjust the hook for Views 3.